# Techniques for creating CFG's

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have to create a CFG which generates

`{a^n (ab)^n c^m d^l e^k | n>0, k, l, m>=0, k<m, m=l+k}`

The first part is easy enough, I came up with

`S -> aS2abS3
S2 -> aS2ab | epsilon`

However, the second part is very confusing. So far I have

`S3 -> S4 | epsilon`

The problem I have is how do I possibly keep track of all of these variables? K has to be less than m, m has to be equal to l + k, and l must be at least 1 by extension. Can someone give me some general tips for approaching these CFG's?

Comment: In retrospect, that answer went a bit too far, since this is almost certainly homework and you would learn more figuring things out yourself. Here's the tip: PDAs can do palindromes; that's the nature of a stack. So you always have to try to make strings mirror images of one form or another. a^m b^m is a trivial form of mirror iamge (where the mirror turns a's into b's). This one is just a little more complicated, but if you focus on looking for the symmetry, you'll find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think inside out (because that's the way CFGs work) and don't get confused by extraneous details.

Here's the tip: CFGs are push-down automata (PDAs) which mean that they have a stack. PDAs are good at symmetry but they can't do antisymmetry. So they can do palindromes, but not repetitions. That's the nature of a stack.

So you always need to look for the mirror images. For example, `ambm` is a trivial form of mirror iamge, where the mirror turns `a`s into `b`s.

This one is just a little more complicated, but if you focus on looking for the symmetry, you'll find it.

Having said that, here's the solution:

Since `m > l`,

```
cmdlek
```

can be rewritten as:

```
cm-lcldlek
```

And since `k = m - l`, that's the same as:

```
ckcldlek
```

From there it's trivial:

```
Sinner → cd | c Sinner d
Souter → Sinner | c Souter e
```

Comment: @ConnerRPanarella: If that's not obvious, try it with pencil and paper. What does Souter produce?

Comment: Ah I get it now. This actually isn't homework I'm reviewing for a test and this is a practice question.